# Replace multiple values in dictionary in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace multiple values in a list of dict. 
Example:

```
# this will set the schema and table dynamically based on the input.
input = {'schema_name': 'test_schema', 'stage_table': 'test_table'}
# need to replace the schemaname and stagetable from the input dict
output = [{id:100, 'query':'SELECT DISTINCT column FROM ${SchemaName}.${StageTable}'}]
# desired output
final_output = select distinct column_name from test_schema.test_table
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `format`-method for strings but you need to adjust the variable names:

```
# this will set the schema and table dynamically based on the input.
fill = {'schema_name': 'test_schema', 'stage_table': 'test_table'}
# need to replace the schemaname and stagetable from the input dict
output = [{id:100, 'query':'SELECT DISTINCT column FROM ${schema_name}.${stage_table}'}]
```

I adjusted the names in and of you `input`-array so that they matched the signature of your string. And now I'll show you how you can use the `format`:

```
output[0]['query'].format(**fill)
#'SELECT DISTINCT column FROM $test_schema.$test_table'
```

to get your desired result.